# Query the output destination of a bazel target, with --symlink_prefix

Tags: bazel

Can bazel tell me where `--symlink_prefix` points?

Different users have different `~/.bazelrc` files, which specify different values for this flag. I'd like to query, in a given workspace, where the binary files will get (or have been) written to.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Since you're looking for this info, you might be trying to do something non-hermetic. In any case I don't think rules can retrieve this information.

Comment: Thanks @laszlo, yes, definitely non-hermetic. I'm trying to copy the bazel build output to a deployment location. For this I need to know where bazel has written its output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bazel info bazel-bin` and `bazel info bazel-genfiles` will tell you the absolute paths.